# How to remove the spinner border?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to remove the black border from these spinners

Here is a screenshot

[image]

PS: If I have missed to provide some vital information, please say so and I will enter here whatever needed.

Comment: You should use custom adapter

Comment: can you be a little bit more specific? I am fairly new to Android ~ 1 month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MySpinnerStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MySpinnerStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">#FFEEEEEE</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @AhmedEkri I tried this but I still have big black margin in my spinner My parent style is `parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" is there a way to solve it? Thank you.